# How do I force visual studio to remake the web.config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

In the middle of creating a web app i more or less destroyed the web.config file i was using and now it has stopped updating it automatically. Is there a way to force visual studio to "remake" the file?

EDIT: i know how to create a new web.config but once its been edited and saved there seems to be now way to make it go back to being updated by changes you make to the program. Seems like a missing setting or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[There is a walkthrough on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8x4ket8%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

To create a Web.config file

In Solution Explorer, click the Refresh icon to make sure that a Web.config file does not already exist for your application.

If you have already used the Web Site Administration Tool or some other means of configuring your application, a Web.config file might have been created automatically.

Clicking Refresh updates your file list.

In Solution Explorer, right-click your Web site name, and then click Add New Item.

In the Templates window, click Web Configuration File.

The file name in the Name text box should be Web.config. You can give the file another name, but this is the default. The .config file name extension is protected from being downloaded by ASP.NET.

Click Add to create the file and open it for editing.

The file contains the code shown in the "Example" section later in this topic, with a few initial defaults. Your application inherits all configuration settings from the Machine.config and Web.config files in the %SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\\CONFIG directory, but you will not see those default settings here. Application-level or directory-level Web.config files only need to be created if you want to override the inherited default settings or add to collection elements like httpHandlers.

To view all of the configuration settings for your current application, you could run the code included in the topic How to: View Inherited and Local Configuration Settings Programmatically. Alternatively, you can view the Machine.config.comments or Web.config.comments files (which also contain useful comments) in the %SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\\CONFIG directory, but these two files will not contain all of your run-time settingsHow to: View Inherited and Local Configuration Settings Programmatically.

If you have changed your Web.config file, save it.

Saving a Web.config file restarts the application. You can alternatively use the configSource attribute of individual section elements to point to a secondary configuration file that does not cause an application restart when it is changed. For more information, see configSource in General Attributes Inherited by Section Elements.

Comment: Guess i should be more specific, I know how to just make a new one or edit one that already exists the problem is it is not automatically updating when i add things like it does with a new project. Kind of a once edited by me it breaks it from doing it on its own. Ive actually had this happen multiple times where i can't remember exactly what i changed and can't Undo it and have ended up starting over from scratch to resolve it.

Comment: @RustyH - " i can't remember exactly what i changed" - this is what source control is for... I.e. Microsoft [Visual Studio Online](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-online-overview-vs.aspx) is free for up to 5 people...